# Placing bullets inside a <dd> shows random chars on the browser

Tags: html

I have this html on an aspx page

```
<dd><strong>A:</strong> The following reasons are the most common for a returned check:<br>
                • Due to Non Sufficient Funds (NSF)<br>
                • Due to inability to locate account<br>                
                • Due to stop payment from the bank<br>
                </dd>
```

But when I display it, it show as random chars instead of the bullets...

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ASCII bullets instead `&bull;`:

```
<dd><strong>A:</strong> The following reasons are the most common for a returned check:
    <br>&bull; Due to Non Sufficient Funds (NSF)
    <br>&bull; Due to inability to locate account
    <br>&bull; Due to stop payment from the bank
    <br>
</dd>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dnxsmj7p/)**

Or put a unordered list inside your description/definition list.

```
<dl>
    <dt><strong>A:</strong> The following reasons are the most common for a returned 
    check:</dt>
    <dd>
    <ul>
        <li>Due to Non Sufficient Funds (NSF) </li>
        <li>Due to inability to locate account </li>
        <li>Due to stop payment from the bank </li>
    </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7xu5to1p/ - it seems to be working fine here.

Although, you might wanna try this

```
<dd><strong>A:</strong> The following reasons are the most common for a returned check:<br>
                <ul>
                <li> Due to Non Sufficient Funds (NSF)</li>
                <li>  Due to inability to locate account</li>            
                <li>  Due to stop payment from the bank</li>
                </ul>
                </dd>
```